# Need assistance regarding converting UIDatePicker time to timestamp

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker, nstimeinterval

I am trying to convert `UIDatePicker` hour and minute into timestamp like this

```
- (IBAction)datePickerValueChanged:(id)sender {
    NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];

    [outputFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];

    self.timeLbl.text = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:self.theDatePicker.date];

    NSTimeInterval ti = [self.theDatePicker.date timeIntervalSince1970];

    NSString *sit = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", ti];

    NSLog(@"%@", sit);
}
```

I want convert `UIDatePicker` hour and minute to timestamp not the seconds. How to achieve this? because  I am testing through this website http://www.epochconverter.com/ but I am setting seconds. I want like 11:05 am/pm not the seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[outputFormatter stringFromDate:self.theDatePicker.date]` produces a string you need. Just NSLog this instead of sit.